# convert ASCII code to number

Tags: perl, numbers, integer, ascii, data-conversion

I have one file, which contain 12 columns (bam file), the eleventh column contain ASCII code. In one file I have more than one ASCII code. I would like to convert it to number.
I think it this code:

```
perl -e '$a=ord("ALL_ASCII_CODES_FROM-FILE"); print "$a\t"'
```

And I would like to create for cycle to read all ASCII codes, which are in eleventh column, convert it to number and count the results to one number.

Comment: show sample input and output.  "convert [more than one ASCII code] to number" could any of many, many different things.

Comment: Input is one column with ASCII codes. Output is same column of numbers, which are convert using by ORD function (convert ASCII to number). After this I count this numbers and divide it by sum of rows...

Comment: describing input is very different than showing it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to split the string into individual characters, loop over every character, and call `ord` in the loop.

```
my @codes = map ord, split //, $str;
say join '.', map { sprintf("%02X", $_) } @codes;
```

Conveniently, `unpack 'C*'` does all of that.

```
my @codes = unpack 'C*', $str;
say join '.', map { sprintf("%02X", $_) } @codes;
```

If you do intend to print it out in hex, you can use the `v` modifier in a `printf`.

```
say sprintf("%v02X", $str);
```

Comment: +1 for the `v` modifier. Why not `say unpack "H*", $str;` though? (Also, we seem to have interpreted the question a bit differently -- we'll see which one of us guessed closer to the OP's actual intent.)

Comment: @Ilmari Karonen, That doesn't work with all characters, though it does work for all of ASCII. It also doesn't separate characters.

Comment: Literally none of these recommendations work, i get runtime syntax errors for these. Function say doesn't exist for me.

Comment: @Owl, Read the docs for `say`.

Answer (score 4):

The natural tool to convert a string of characters into a list of the corresponding ASCII codes would be [unpack](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/unpack.html):

```
my @codes = unpack "C*", $string;
```

In particular, assuming that you're parsing the QUAL column of an [SAM file](http://samtools.sourceforge.net/SAMv1.pdf) (or, more generally, any [FASTQ-style quality string](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FASTQ_format#Quality), I believe the correct conversion would be:

```
my @qual = map {$_ - 33} unpack "C*", $string;
```

Ps. From your mention of "columns", I'm assuming you're actually parsing a SAM file, not a BAM file.  If I'm reading the spec correctly, the BAM format doesn't seem to use the +33 offset for quality values, so if you *are* parsing BAM files, you'd simply use the first example above for that.